# Laravel/Lumen не отображается картинка при отправке имейла на gmail почту

Tags: laravel, sendmail, lumen

Использую Lumen:

blade файл

```
<img width="30" height="30" src="{{ 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents(URL::asset('/images/social/instagram.png'))) }}">
```

при отправке имейла на gmail почту картинка не отображается

пробовал так:

```
 <img width="30" height="30" src="{{ 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($message->embed('/images/social/instagram.png'))) }}">
```

но тогда выходит ошибка: Undefined variable: message
Использую Lumen
Подскажите как решить проблему
На почты temp-mail протестировал там все ок, картинки отображаются

Comment: Попробуйте отправить картинка через URL URL::asset('/images/social/instagram.png') не base64
 <img width="30" height="30" src="URL::asset('/images/social/instagram.png')">

Comment: я так пробовал, но это не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен!
Нужно использовать прямую ссылку из браузера так как gmail.com не может получить доступ на локальные изображения и будет принять их как не безопасное

```
 <img width="30" height="30" src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png">
```

и браузер не будет принять это как небезопасное и это работает